# Chrome Extension - Page action stopped working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I have a chrome extension (unfortunately private for a specific group) in which I have a page action icon.

I have been using this extension for years, and distributed it in Chrome store. But suddenly, when creating a new version of the extension, the page action just stopped working at all! (Last time I deployed it was April 21, 2020, and it was working correctly in debug mode)

I made some tests and this is the weirdest:

- If I use the extension I installed from the store, the moment I activate the extension in the settings, the page action icon appears (although disabled as expected)
- If I disable the store extension and load it unpacked (exactly the same source code I uploaded to the store), the page action doesn't show anymore! (I'm sure the code is the same, took from the very same zip file I uploaded to the store)

What is going on? Did Google change anything? How can I make the page action work again?

This is how it is in the extension and how it used to work flawlessly even in debug mode:

**manifest.json**

```
"permissions": ["declarativeContent", "storage"],

"icons": {
    "16": "Icons/Icon16.png",
    "32": "Icons/Icon32.png",
    "48": "Icons/Icon48.png",
    "128": "Icons/Icon128.png"
},

"page_action": {
    "default_popup": "Settings_Page/settings_page.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "Icons/Icon16.png",
        "32": "Icons/Icon32.png",
        "48": "Icons/Icon48.png",
        "128": "Icons/Icon128.png"
    }
}, 

"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "install.js",
        "other.js",
        "another.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
},
```

Where `install.js` looks like this:

```
//installation setup
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    console.log("on installed add listener start");
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        console.log("declarative content page changed start");
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules(
        [{
            conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'somepage.domain.com'},}) //hid the url here, but it's correct
            ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
        }]);
        console.log("declarative content page changed end");
    });
    console.log("on installed add listener end");
});
```

I double checked that the `install.js` is being correctly run by seeing all four console messages displayed.

Comment: Nothing was changed in the API. I don't see problems in the posted fragments of code so it's either a bug in Chrome or in your other code not shown here. See if it works in an older portable Chrome.

Comment: Do you know any trustable source for older portable Chromes? I'm totally sure I didn't change a bit of the code, and it was working perfectly on April 21 this year.

Comment: Use https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py

Comment: Something definitely changed in Chrome or in the API. I tried another extension, also straight from the zip without a single change. The store version creates page action, the debug version doesn't.

Comment: Maybe you look in the wrong place: in the new Chrome extensions are hidden by default inside the puzzle piece icon menu.

Comment: .... that moment when you get ashamed because it was right in front of your face.... Thank you. If you post it as an answer you'll get it.

Comment: It's a bad UI change and Chrome's developers don't want to admit it, they just ignore all feedback.

Comment: If at least the behavior for activating the extensions from the store were the same, I would have suspected something.